# Must declare the table variable "@TempTable"

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, dacpac

I want to add a script post-deployment to insert data. But when I execute this script below I got this message error:

> Must declare the table variable "@TempTable".

The purpose of this script it's to force adding Id which is a primary key, I know that we can use:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[TableName] ON;
GO
```

and after the Merge

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[TableName] OFF;
GO
```

But it's not working for me I can't deploy my DacPac

```
DECLARE @vehicleType TABLE(
    [VehicleTypeId] BIGINT, 
    [Name] NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
);



INSERT INTO @VehicleType ([VehicleTypeId], [Name]) 
VALUES(1,'Automobile'),(2,'HeavyVehicle'),(3,'Motorcycle')

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[VehicleType] ON;
GO

MERGE INTO [dbo].[VehicleType]
    USING  @VehicleType as vhlt
        ON ([dbo].[VehicleType].[VehicleTypeId] = vhtl.[VehicleTypeId] and [dbo].[VehicleType].[Name] = vhlt.[Name])
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
            INSERT VALUES ([VehicleTypeId], [Name]);

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[VehicleType] OFF;
GO
```

Comment: `GO` terminates the batch. The table variable falls out of scope there. Remove it (after `SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[VehicleType] ON;`).

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10539470/must-declare-the-table-variable

Comment: Thank you @madreflection for your answer but it still not working but not the same message error : 

An explicit value for the identity column in table 'dbo.VehicleType' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

Comment: no cause I use  " Set Identity_Insert" to force Primary key and I didn't find a solution for this !

Comment: Tangent question: what's the primary key of `dbo.VehicleType`? Is it `VehicleTypeId`, or both `VehicleTypeId` and `Name`?

Comment: *"An explicit value for the identity column in table 'dbo.VehicleType' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON."* - It's clearly stating that you need to specify the column names after `INSERT`, so `INSERT ([VehicleTypeId], [Name]) VALUES ([vhlt].[VehicleTypeId], [vhlt].[Name])`.

Comment: The primary key it's just VehicleTypeId @madreflection

Comment: In that case, your `ON` clause is too restrictive. If someone accidentally changed the `Name` column, it would not match and create a new row, thus violating the primary key constraint.

Comment: I try it, but I Still have the same message Error, it's weird.. @madreflection

Comment: I'm working on an answer based on your response to my question. Just hang tight.

Comment: Okey @madreflection Thank you for your help

Comment: you're right  I should add  Insert ([VehicleTypeId], [Name]) @madreflection  Thank you !!

Comment: You're welcome. I have more suggestions, though. Stay tuned.

Comment: Me too I will add something : when we want to force a primary key we add :  
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[VehicleType] ON; before the DECLARE 
@madreflection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that I need to point out is that a lookup table such as this should *not* have an auto-number (`IDENTITY`) column.  Auto-number values are *synthetic* and should only be used when you *don't care* what the value is, just that it's unique.  That works well when users can add values to the lookup set.

For non-user-serviceable lookup tables, like your `VehicleType`, you *do* care what the `VehicleTypeId` values are so auto-number works against you.  If you can remove the `IDENTITY` property from the column definition, you absolutely should.  If you can't, you're stuck using `IDENTITY_INSERT`.  Just remember not to use `IDENTITY` in future lookup table designs.

---

There's a way to do this without the table variable: use a CTE with the `MERGE` statement.

The CTE will contain all the values you want using unioned static `SELECT` statements (using `UNION ALL` skips duplicate checks since you know there won't be any duplicates). 
 The `MERGE` statement uses the CTE as its source table.

The `ON` clause in the `MERGE` statement should only compare the primary key.  If a value in a non-key column was changed, it would cause a new row to be inserted; the new row would violate the primary key.  Instead, update the `Name` column to the value in the CTE.  To do that, I've added a `WHEN MATCHED` clause below.

I suggest always using `dst` and `src` as aliases in a `MERGE` statement.  The `MERGE` statement can involve a lot of different parts.  If you use the same aliases for the source and target/destination tables, that's one less bit of complexity you have to worry about.  I've seen this actually help developers learn the syntax and this technique.

I like to name the CTE `src` so I don't actually have to alias it.

```sql
-- Only IF you cannot remove the IDENTITY property from VehicleTypeId:
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[VehicleType] ON;
GO

-- Stage the data and merge it into the table in one shot:
WITH [src] ([VehicleTypeId], [Name])
AS
(
    SELECT           1, 'Automobile'
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'HeavyVehicle'
    UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'Motorcycle'
)
MERGE INTO [dbo].[VehicleType] AS [dst]
USING [src]
    ON [dst].[VehicleTypeId] = src.[VehicleTypeId]
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT ([VehicleTypeId], [Name])
    VALUES ([src].[VehicleTypeId], [src].[Name])
WHEN MATCHED AND ([dst].[Name] <> [src].[Name]) THEN
    UPDATE
    SET [Name] = [src].[Name]
;
GO

-- Again, only IF you cannot remove the IDENTITY property from VehicleTypeId:
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[VehicleType] OFF;
GO
```

When I write a script like this that I intend to run from SSMS, I include an `OUTPUT` clause so I can see what happened and verify that it was right.

```sql
...
OUTPUT $action AS [*Action],
    COALESCE([inserted].[VehicleTypeId], [deleted].[VehicleTypeId]) AS [=VehicleTypeId],
    [deleted].[Name] AS [-Name],
    [inserted].[Name] AS [+Name]
    -- Repeat deleted and inserted AS -/+ for remaining non-key columns.
;
```

A note about the prefixes I've used in the aliases:

- `*` for metadata columns (really, it's only ever `*Action`).
- `=` for the primary key columns.  They won't change, so only one per column in the key.
- `-` for the old values (e.g. `-Name`).
- `+` for the new values (e.g. `+Name`).